# Krull's Height Theorem Proof.

Tags: ring-theory

http://www2.gsu.edu/~matfxe/commalglectures/lect14.pdf

Here is a proof of Krull's PIT theorem. I don't understand why $\cap_{t\geq 1} (PR_{P})^t = 0$ (written on Page 2, line 3)

If anyone would shed some light that would be great!

Comment: Look at the proof of the Krull intersection theorem [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Rees_lemma).

Answer (score 1):

It follows from [Nakayama's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma) for $M=\bigcap_{t\geq 1} (PR_P)^t$ and $I=PR_P.$